# Randomly reorder digits of an integer (but '0' should never be at the beginning)

Tags: r

I need to randomly reorder digits of an integer `x` (at least 4 or more digits). The following sort of works but does not ensure that zero never comes at the beginning of the reordered value.

If zero were to become the initial value, the reordered integer would have less `nchar` which is what I am trying to avoid.

```
x = 357230434L
set.seed(42)
as.integer(paste(sample(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),""))), collapse = ""))
#[1] 437324035
```

I haven't tried yet but I may be able to do it with `for` loop. However, before I attempt that, I wanted to see if there is a better way to reorder digits of an integer while ensuring that a zero is never placed at the beginning of the reordered integer.

Comment: What is the intended behavior when `x=0`?

Comment: @aryamccarthy, `x` will always have more than 4 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered doing it in multiple parts? There might be an easier way, but one way would be to randomly pull the first non-zero character and then sample the rest. Something like:

```
  chars<-unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),""))
  first<-sample(chars[chars!="0"],1)
  as.integer(paste0(c(first,sample(chars[-match(first,chars)])),collapse=""))
```

Running it with a few different seeds:

```
set.seed(42) #447323035
set.seed(43) #243057343
set.seed(44) #472333504
set.seed(45) #475433320
set.seed(46) #570244333
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party, but here is another approach:

1. generate a random permutation
2. shift its circularly to make it starts with the first non-zero element (`01234` becomes `12340`)

Code:

```
# random permutation
x2 = sample(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ""))) 
# get the position of the first non-zero character
p = which(x2 > '0')[1] 
# make a circular rotation to put the non-zero in front
x2[(seq_along(x2) + p-2) %% length(x2) + 1]
```

Also, don't forget to set `options(scipen=16)` or another large value, otherwise you will be in troubles with the scientific notation:

```
> as.character(100000000)
[1] "1e+08"
```